# How to use Knockout Mapping plugin in Hottowel

Tags: visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, hottowel

i was able to install [ko.mapping](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Mapping/)  in VisualStudio but when i try to map some Json Data in my view it does not work. can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

here is my **viewmodel**

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'services/logger', 'durandal/app', 'mapping'], function (router, ko, logger, app, mapping) {

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Google Books View Activated', null, 'books', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
    //==jquery=================================================
    function attached() {


    }//-->end of viewAttached() 

    //========VIEWMODEL========================================
    var ViewModel = function (data) {
        activate = activate;
        attached = attached;
        title = 'google Books';

    };

    return new ViewModel();

});
```

and here ist an working example in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/6CS9F/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you don't need to return a new View Model. you just need to return the view model.

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'services/logger', 'durandal/app', 'mapping'],
  function (router, ko, logger, app, mapping) {
    var books = ko.observableArray();
    function activate() {
      getBooks().then(function(){
        logger.log('Google Books View Activated', null, 'books', true);
        return true;
      });
    }
    function attached() {
    }
    function getBooks(){
      $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        vm.books(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        return true;
      });
    }

    var vm = {
      activate : activate,
      attached : attached,
      title : 'google Books',
      books: books
    };

    return vm;
});
```

**EDIT**
To find requirejs errors add to your main.js file.  It should help in tracking down requirejs module loading errors.

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    console.log(err.requireType);
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
    }

    throw err;
};
```

Comment: in that case you need to expose the a books collection on the viewmodel,  I have edited the answer to better answer the question.  I would also look at removing the data retrieval into its own JavaScript file.

Comment: Have a look at [https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal] which is a sample app from the Author of HotTowel.